# Cython construct sorted array

Tags: arrays, sorting, insert, cython

Using `Cython`, I'm building a program in whcih I am constructing an array of known length, say of length `10e5`. I have to separately calculate each element and then add it to the array, which I initialize as `np.empty(int(10e5), dtype=np.float64)` with help of the `numpy` package.

However, I want this array to be sorted, and the `np.ndarray.sort` operation takes about 17% of my program's total runtime, so I would like to eliminate this step.

Is there a fast Cython-esque way to construct the array in a way where it is kept sorted as more values are added?
I tried something using a [TreeSet](https://github.com/fukatani/TreeSet) but this object-oriented approach generates way too much overhead.

Comment: Insertion sort on a binary search tree, what TreeSet does, might give better performance on average, however, it requires moving the data from an array into a heap/tree structure to take advantage of binary search. That will likely induce more overhead than is saved by the sort. I'd also be surprised if numpy sort did not already use insertion sort for small lists. For larger lists, and arrays in particular, the built in sort is faster.

Comment: Do you need to sort after every insertion or only once, when all elements are inserted?

Comment: @danny for a fixed max heap size as in this example you can use an array to store the heap entries and encode the tree structure using the indices into the array as described e.g. here: http://www.cse.hut.fi/en/research/SVG/TRAKLA2/tutorials/heap_tutorial/taulukkona.html

Comment: @ngoldbaum That is very useful thank you, had not considered that. So that would take time complexity for heap sort to `O(log n)` for a fixed size array. Still not convinced this will be faster than quicksort and would depend on how fast the respective implementations are - some profiling would be needed.

Comment: @danny I _might_ try to implement profile this in the somewhat nearby future but it's not a priority for me (anymore) at this point.